# Where can I see a jujucharms deployment in my AWS console

Tags: juju, amazon-ec2

I can see through the Jujucharms website that my model has been deployed, but I can not see anything in my AWS console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When viewing your AWS console be sure you're viewing the same region that you've chosen to deploy to using JAAS as the AWS console doesn't provide an aggregate view.

Comment: It automatically deployed to Ireland... The next time I did it I chose my own region.